# How to add multiple values as an object to a single parameter in a jQuery ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to add multiple values to a specific data parameter `'category_values'` when check boxes are checked.

```
category = []
                jQuery('#rpd_filter_categ:checked').map(function() {
                    category.push(jQuery(this).attr('data-value'));
                }); 

category = jQuery('#rpd_filter_categ:checked').attr('data-value');

jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        // dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            'action'            :   'ajax_filter_listings',
            'action_values'     :   action,
            'category_values'   :   category,
            ...
        },
        success: ...

function ajax_filter_listings(){
$categ_array              =   '';

     $allowed_html   =   array();
        if (isset($_POST['category_values']) && trim($_POST['category_values']) != 'All Types' && $_POST['category_values']!=''&& $_POST['category_values']!='all' && $_POST['category_values']!='all-types'){
            $taxcateg_include   =   sanitize_title ( wp_kses(  $_POST['category_values'],$allowed_html  ) );
            $categ_array=array(
                'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $taxcateg_include
            );
        }
```

It works for a single checked option but with 2+ options checked either gets:

- No results
- Only 1st option alphabetically
- Last option selected

When I check `console -> request -> postData` it either:

- Adds characters between values `%2C`
- Creates a new Object for second value

I've just confused myself further the more I look at this... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: To try and better explain...I'm trying to use the data-value attribute (apartments, townhomes, houses etc) to create array/object to send to jQuery ajax request as 'category_values'  so that when options are checked the php filters the results with those data-values..

Answer (score 0):

Your fields all appear to have the same id (`rpd_filter_categ`) but ids should be unique so it would be better to use this as a class name.

Using the class you could get your categories like this:

```
var categories = [];
jQuery('.rpd_filter_categ:checked').each(function() {
  categories.push(jQuery(this).attr('data-value'));
});

jQuery.ajax({
etc...
```

Comment: Oh I saw that, thought I had fixed that or maybe I copied over it.. anyhow targeting by id or class still returns the same result.. When running your example above it works with one checkbox selected it filters results accurately. Once a 2nd checkbox it only displays results for the last option checked (within array). I can console.log and see it's added..

Within chrome I can go to console -> Object -> request -> postData -> params: and it creates an additional object with name and value in each object and seems to only read the last?

Comment: What output do you get if you add `console.log(categories);` just before the `ajax` call?

Comment: Both before and after ajax request are the same: 
["apartments", "townhomes"] but it only filters to results for townhomes.

Comment: So the categories are being posted correctly, what is the output of `$categ_array`?